# Java is connecting to SQL database but it isn't updating tables

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

I am coding a ticket system using java and SQLite. Here is the code I have for connecting to the DB and creating a ticket in that DB.

```
public class TicketProject {

    static Connection conn = null;
    static Scanner entry = new Scanner(System.in);
    static PreparedStatement add = null;

    public static Connection ConnectDB(){
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:TicketDB.db");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Connection Success!");
            return conn;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException | HeadlessException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connection failed ! " + e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void createTicket() {

        String cont = "1";
        int contChoice = Integer.parseInt(cont);
        Statement stmt = null;

        while (contChoice != 0) {

            try {
                //program accepts user input
                System.out.print("Enter Name: ");
                String n = entry.nextLine();
                System.out.print("Enter Department: ");
                String d = entry.nextLine();
                System.out.print("Enter Status: ");
                String s = entry.nextLine();
                System.out.print("Enter Notes: ");
                String o = entry.nextLine();

                add = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Ticket VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)");
                add.setString(2, n);
                add.setDate(3, java.sql.Date.valueOf(java.time.LocalDate.now()));
                add.setString(4, d);
                add.setString(5, s);
                add.setString(6, o);
                int executeUpdate = add.executeUpdate();               
            } catch (SQLException e ) {

            }

            System.out.println("Would you like to create another ticket? 1 = yes, 0 = no");
            cont = entry.nextLine();
            contChoice = Integer.parseInt(cont);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ConnectDB();

        String initialOption;
        int run = 1;

        while (run != 2) {

            System.out.println("What would you like to do?");
            System.out.println("1 = Create Ticket, 2 = Edit Ticket, 3 = Display Tickets, 4 = Exit");
            initialOption = entry.nextLine();
            int choice = Integer.parseInt(initialOption);

            if (choice == 1) {

                createTicket();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

So in this code we see my connection to the DB, we see my createTicket function and we see in the main that we call the connection and then call createTicket. The Ticket table has been created manually and actually has 6 fields. This code here lists 5, but the first field is TicketNumber which is a non-null auto-increment.

I have tried what is seen here, add.executeUpdate(), I have also tried add.execute() and conn.commit(). No matter what I try the database does not update when I run the code and enter information.

What am I doing wrong? If you need any other information please let me know.

Thanks in advance

Comment: We need you to add a System.out.println(); inside of your SQLException catch block so you can see a message about what's going wrong. Right now, you just skip past any SQLException without even knowing if an error occured. The SQLException will inform you about what went wrong if you print e.getMessage(). That's how you know what went wrong.

Comment: I added this code: 
         System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
         System.exit(0);
It isn't spitting out an error other than the one I have listed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though the way you do is not ideal, just to check whether what is going on use the following syntax in the Insert statement. ie. put the columns list, other than the identity col, in the proper order

```
Insert Into Ticket (Col1,Col2,... ) values (...)
```

Better way is to use the parameters, and have a stored procedure to do the insert

Comment: Ok, I will try this. Should it list out all the fields including the ticket number, which I initially ignore, or will only listing the 5 that accept input work?

Comment: not the identity col ( so 5 cols only - I edited my answer)

Comment: Ok, something new happened. I have gotten this error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 5 out of bounds for length 5
 at org.sqlite.core.CorePreparedStatement.batch(CorePreparedStatement.java:130)
 at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3PreparedStatement.setString(JDBC3PreparedStatement.java:417)
 at ticketproject.TicketProject.createTicket(TicketProject.java:64)

Comment: Is that just after, you changing the insert statement, or did you make any other changes?

Comment: Just changed the insert statement. This error points to the Notes field. This field accepts TEXT and has the same attributes as Department and Status.

Comment: I think your set of add.setString(2 ..., add.setString(3 ... has to start from 1
as


                add.setString(1, n);
                add.setDate(2, java.sql.Date.valueOf(java.time.LocalDate.now()));
                add.setString(3, d);
                add.setString(4, s);
                add.setString(5, o);

Comment: This was it! It works now!!!! Thanks so much. I still have to play with the date because it isn't populating that field correctly, but my database is populating. Thanks again.